# vector projection on to subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If given a subspace of *R4* that is spanned by the set of orthogonal vectors **W** =span { (0,1,1,1),(1,1,0,-1) }. How to find the projection of a vector ***u*** onto the subspace?

if **u** = (2,1,2,0)?

What I have tried doing is to find a vector, **v** that is perpendicular to the set **W** and do an orthogonal projection of **u** onto **v**. But this did not work.

I am not looking for an answer, just some help on how I should interpret the set **W** in this question.

Comment: Hint:Not only is $(0,1,1,1)\cdot(1,1,0,-1)=0$, but also  $(0,1,1,1)\cdot (0,1,1,1)=3$ and $(1,1,0,-1)\cdot (1,1,0,-1)=3$. Now what does $\mathbf u\cdot(0,1,1,1)=3$ and $\mathbf u\cdot(1,1,0,-1)=3$ tell you?

Comment: well it shows that u is not orthogonal to the set, not sure what you mean though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do these steps:

- Construct an orthonormal basis $(v,w)$ of $W$ using the Gram-Schmidt procedure
- hence the projection of $u$ onto $W$ is
  $$p_W(u)=\langle u,v\rangle v+\langle u,w\rangle w$$